# Why am I getting "Could not resolve all files for configuration"?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

This is the stacktrace for the error I am observing:

```
ERROR:C:\Web Development\VS code\Flutter.projects\project1\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
```

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :path_provider_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Web Development\VS code\Flutter.projects\project1\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
```

Comment: Where is your code? What did you try to do, when the error occurred? What is your question?

Comment: you are trying to get the length of a null string, provide code to allow others help.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Multidex

In you app goto **android/app/build.gradle**

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    val multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version")
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://developer.android.com/build/multidex)